# FFMPEG, resize and pad a video by and odd number of pixels?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm trying to resize and pad a video from `1917 x 1080` to `1920 x 1080`.

I've tried various syntax, which works but doesn't change the size.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=1920:1080,pad=1920:1080 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

However, I have go to this point by resize, joint audio and rotate. The initial size is `640 x 1136`, I believe this is the source of the problem.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=900:1200 -c:a copy output.mp4

ffmpeg \
-i input.m4a \
-i resize.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -shortest \
output.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mp4" -vf "transpose=2" output/mp4
```

So I'm wondering if I should do something different earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this on the original video,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v transpose=2,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

You can add the audio in. if you want.